# java swing jbutton

Tags: java, swing, background

Доброй ночи.  Рисую линию из квадратов jbutton на jpanel, когда собирается - линию убираю, jbutton - те что выше отпускаю. Ну так вот, оказалось что background удаленных элементов остается. Т.е. сами элементы убираются, но цвет остается. Если подвести фигуру по X, но выше, background исчезает. Как можно обновить... background или отрисовку, даже не знаю как сформулировать...

з/ы наверное можно просто убрать панель, создать новую и отрисовать заново... но зачем изобретать велосипед...

[two muppets http://savepic.org/8470746.jpg](http://savepic.org/8470746.jpg)

Comment: мда, задал вопрос и сразу нашел ответ. **.repaint():** мне помог. Не откажусь почитать, если кто-что добавит.)

Comment: `JButton` - это же целая кнопка, а не просто набор пикселей в виде прямоугольника. Не знаю насчет итоговой производительности, но само по себе звучит странно и неправильно: рисовать с помощью кнопок. Со _Swing_ почти не работал, но наверняка там есть Canvas или его аналог для отрисовки в том числе и игрового поля.

Comment: Знаю, это просто практика. Первое что пришло в голову, реализовал. Нашел "баг" - исправляю. Когда будет сделано как задумал, уже можно будет думать о оптимизации...)